# How can I count the number of occurrences previously appearing in the same column with arrayformula()

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates

I am receiving email addresses submitted via a google form so I need to autopopulate the 3rd column - "count".
I need to count the number of PREVIOUS occurrences of an email address in the same column.
An example of the desired output can be seen below.

**Please note that the information is received from a Google form and therefore new lines are automatically appended so I need the formula also to be automatically added in the new row.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the email adresses in column B, starting in row 2 you can try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B), COUNTIFS(B2:B, B2:B, ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B))-1,))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the "COUNTIF(<range>, <condition>)" method.
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en

If column A is full of email adresses, then the cells in column B could have the method `=COUNTIF($A$1:A1, A1)-1`, `=COUNTIF($A$1:A2, A2)-1`, `=COUNTIF($A$1:A3, A3)-1` and so on.

Each cell counts all cells in column A whose content matches exactly the one to the left.

See this sheet for a clearer example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fAHYAFZM1ZUGnEqErdwyXS5MsGZPvM2LEsaU1NqNM34/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: As mentioned above, please note that the information is received from a Google form and therefore new lines are automatically appended. I need the new line to automatically contain the formula